# Unity Config error in console application

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, console-application, unity-container

Hi am working on console application which uses Dependency Injection pattern, i have created the interface like

```
  public interface IRecurringTransactionPlanDataService : IService<RecurringTransactionPlan>
  {
    IQueryable<RecurringTransactionPlan> RecurringTransactionPlanData();
  }
```

and the class implements as

```
 public class RecurringTransactionPlanDataService : Service<RecurringTransactionPlan>, IRecurringTransactionPlanDataService
{
    private readonly IRepositoryAsync<RecurringTransactionPlan> _repository;

    public RecurringTransactionPlanDataService(IRepositoryAsync<RecurringTransactionPlan> repository)
        : base(repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public IQueryable<RecurringTransactionPlan> RecurringTransactionPlanData()
    {
        return _repository.RecurringTransactionPlanData();
    }
}
```

The repository:

```
 public static class RecurringTransactionPlanRepository
{
    public static IQueryable<RecurringTransactionPlan> RecurringTransactionPlanData(this IRepository<RecurringTransactionPlan> repository)
    {
        return repository.Queryable();
    } 
}
```

the above code all in separate projects, i am using this in MVC and also in console application, while using in MVC there is no error fetching data from db by UnityConfig.cs, but in console application we need to manually register and resolve the interfaces, i have tried this,

My Console Application:

```
 public class RecurringTransaction
{
    public readonly IRecurringTransactionPlanDataService _recurringTransactionPlanDataService;

    public RecurringTransaction()
    { 
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IRecurringTransactionPlanDataService, RecurringTransactionPlanDataService>();
        _recurringTransactionPlanDataService = container.Resolve<IRecurringTransactionPlanDataService>();

    } 
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        FeePaymentTracker.UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();

        RecurringTransaction rt = new RecurringTransaction();
        var restult = rt.GetRecurringTransactionRecords();
    }
}
```

[image]

am getting the above error. expecting your ideas to resolve the error.

Comment: You are using Service Locator pattern, not dependency injection. You will need to show how you register your types with Unity. I don't even see a `RecurringTransactionPlanDataService` type anywhere in your example.

Comment: please see the edited one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `RecurringTransaction`-method you create a new container and then you register `RecurringTransactionPlanDataService` in that new container. But you do not register the dependencies that the implementation `RecurringTransactionPlanDataService` has. That container will only have one registration.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IRecurringTransactionPlanDataService, RecurringTransactionPlanDataService>();
_recurringTransactionPlanDataService = container.Resolve<IRecurringTransactionPlanDataService>();
```

Since `RecurringTransactionPlanDataService` has a dependency to `IRepositoryAsync<RecurringTransactionPlan>` you need to register that as well.

Change your code to:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IRecurringTransactionPlanDataService, RecurringTransactionPlanDataService>();
container.RegisterType<IRepositoryAsync<RecurringTransactionPlan>, YourRepositoryImplementation>();
_recurringTransactionPlanDataService = container.Resolve<IRecurringTransactionPlanDataService>();
```

As a sidenote you may want to re-use the same container. In console-applications I usually resolve a "ProgramStarter", which then gets the correct injections. This way you only need to use the service locator anti-pattern in the root. But can use proper DI in the rest of the application.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<ProgramStarter, ProgramStarter>();

        // Pass the same container to the config.
        FeePaymentTracker.UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(container);
        var program = container.Resolve<ProgramStarter>();
        program.Run();
    }
}

public class ProgramStarter
{
    IRecurringTransactionPlanDataService _dataService;
    public ProgramStarter(IRecurringTransactionPlanDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the code that you have posted you have an interface called IPaymentService and its implementation. It seems ok. But then in the screenshot you are trying to resolve a dependency called RecurringTransactionPlanDataService. Make your that you have registered this dependency. Could you add information about how you are registering the dependencies in the container?

The problem in your code is that you are trying to resolve the implementation instead of the interface. You should change the following line:

```
_recurringTransactionPlanDataService = container.Resolve<RecurringTransactionPlanDataService>();
```

with that:

```
_recurringTransactionPlanDataService = container.Resolve<IRecurringTransactionPlanDataService>();
```

Cheers,

Comment: i have modified the Interface name for easily understanding, please consider the error in the screen shot itself which is **ResolutionFailedException**,

Comment: Can you show the piece of code where you are registering components in the container? Can you add more information about the exception?

Comment: I have added my console app too

Comment: I see, you should resolve the interface, not the implementation. _recurringTransactionPlanDataService = container.Resolve<IRecurringTransactionPlanDataService>();

Comment: Though its throw the same error after changing to Interface

Comment: Have you registered the IRepositoryAsync?

Comment: Yeah i have registered in my Unity config file.

Comment: But you have to register it in the RecurringTransaction, because you are creating the container there.